# Trying to scrape email address from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to scrape this website:

[www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll=](http://www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll=)

I did scrape it using Scrapy, but I couldn't scrape email addresses. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import ChurchItem


class ChurchSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'church_spider'
    page_number = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll=']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = ChurchItem()
        container = response.css(".icon-ministry")
        for t in container:
            church_name = t.css(".field-name-locator-ministry-title a::text").extract()
            church_phone = t.css(".field-name-field-phone::text").extract()
            church_address = t.css(".thoroughfare::text").extract()
            church_email = t.css(".field-name-field-mu-email span::text").extract()

            items["church_name"] = church_name
            items["church_phone"] = church_phone
            items["church_address"] = church_address
            items["church_email"] = church_email

            yield items

        # next_page = 'https://www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll=&page=' + str(ChurchSpiderSpider.page_number)
        # if ChurchSpiderSpider.page_number <= 110:
        #     ChurchSpiderSpider.page_number += 1
        #     yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I have found a partial solution, but it is still not complete. The output is now like:

```
{'church_address': ['7763 Highway 21'],
 'church_email': ['herbklaehn', ' [at] ', 'gmail.com'],
 'church_name': ['Allenford United Church'],
 'church_phone': ['519-35-6232']}
```

How do I replace `[at]` with `@` and combine the email address into one string?

Comment: pages can use javascript to display email - to stop scraping bots/scripts.

Comment: The mail is displayed in that website as `<div class="label-above">Email: </div><span class="spamspan"><span class="u">alpcharge</span> [at] <span class="d">sasktel.net</span></span></div>` seems like an odd way to display mails. Anyway, don't just look for "mailto" code, that's probably your issue. Instead you will have to scrap the different parts of the mail and build it yourself with a parsing function.

Comment: @Saelyth maybe it seems odd way but it can stop some bots/scripts to scrape mails and send spam. And this is why class has name `spamspan` :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using Beautiful Soup**

A simple way to get the email is to look for the div with `class=field-name-field-mu-email'`, and then replace the odd display to a proper email format.

For instance:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll='

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'field-name-field-mu-email'}):
    print (div.find('span').text.replace(' [at] ', '@'))

Out[1]:
alpcharge@sasktel.net
guc-eug@bellnet.ca
pioneerpastoralcharge@gmail.com
acmeunitedchurch@gmail.com
cmcphers@lakeheadu.ca
mbm@kos.net
tommaclaren@gmail.com
agassizunited@shaw.ca
buchurch@xplornet.com
dmitchell008@yahoo.ca
karen.charlie62@gmail.com
trinityucbdn@westman.wave.ca
gepc.ucc.mail@gmail.com
monacampbell181@gmail.com
herbklaehn@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try webscraping using Selenium, I tried this code and its giving perfect results.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.united-church.ca/search/locator/all?keyw=&mission_units_ucc_ministry_type_advanced=10&locll=")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for all_emails in soup.find_all('a',class_="spamspan"):
    print(all_emails.text)
```

**Results:**

```
alpcharge@sasktel.net
guc-eug@bellnet.ca
pioneerpastoralcharge@gmail.com
acmeunitedchurch@gmail.com
cmcphers@lakeheadu.ca
mbm@kos.net
tommaclaren@gmail.com
agassizunited@shaw.ca
buchurch@xplornet.com
dmitchell008@yahoo.ca
karen.charlie62@gmail.com
trinityucbdn@westman.wave.ca
gepc.ucc.mail@gmail.com
monacampbell181@gmail.com
herbklaehn@gmail.com
```